# Opening XNA Xbox 360 assemblies in Reflector

Tags: .net, compact-framework, xna, reflector, xbox360

I'd like to get a look at the differences between the Xbox 360 and Windows XNA assemblies. I know the 360 runs the .NET Compact Framework and I was under the impression that Reflector could read CF assemblies, but when I open them, all of the methods are blank and no internal classes are shown.

Is this done on purpose, or is it a limitation of Reflector? Is there another way to see how the Xbox 360 XNA assemblies work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of .NET Compact Framework included in XBox 360 is a specially version designed to run on that device only and it is not the same as you have you windows phones. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203912.aspx) for more information.

Probably, that is why reflector can not properly open the assemblies.

Comment: Thanks, although I don't see why they would need to change the format of the assemblies. That article only mentions added classes and features. It could also be that, since the assemblies don't need to actually run on the development machine, Microsoft ships them empty to save space. The real assemblies exist on the Xbox 360 itself and get used when the game is deployed.

Comment: @david MS uses metadata-only assemblies for performance and multitargeting purposes in VS 2008 and above.  If you can open the assemblies in Reflector, and you don't see any method bodies, that's what is going on here.

Comment: Considering that the XDK is a protected trade secret (real Xbox developers need to sign a NDA to use it) I'm sure they don't want people digging through their libraries in Reflector.